# Defining my own OrderedType in Coq

Tags: coq, formal-verification, proof-general

To try to understand how to define my own `OrderedType` in Coq, I'm working my way through the examples of `OrderedType`s given in the standard library in `Coq.Structures.OrderedTypeEx` ([here](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Structures.OrderedTypeEx.html)). As of right now I'm only concerned with the first couple of modules:

```
Require Import OrderedType.
Require Import ZArith.
Require Import Omega.
Require Import NArith Ndec.
Require Import Compare_dec.    

Module Type UsualOrderedType.
 Parameter Inline t : Type.
 Definition eq := @eq t.
 Parameter Inline lt : t -> t -> Prop.
 Definition eq_refl := @eq_refl t.
 Definition eq_sym := @eq_sym t.
 Definition eq_trans := @eq_trans t.
 Axiom lt_trans : forall x y z : t, lt x y -> lt y z -> lt x z.
 Axiom lt_not_eq : forall x y : t, lt x y -> ~ eq x y.
 Parameter compare : forall x y : t, Compare lt eq x y.
 Parameter eq_dec : forall x y : t, { eq x y } + { ~ eq x y }.
End UsualOrderedType.

Module UOT_to_OT (U: UsualOrderedType) <: OrderedType := U.

Module Nat_as_OT <: UsualOrderedType.

  Definition t := nat.

  Definition eq := @eq nat.
  Definition eq_refl := @eq_refl t.
  Definition eq_sym := @eq_sym t.
  Definition eq_trans := @eq_trans t.

  Definition lt := lt.

  Lemma lt_trans : forall x y z : t, lt x y -> lt y z -> lt x z.        

  Lemma lt_not_eq : forall x y : t, lt x y -> ~ eq x y.

  Definition compare x y : Compare lt eq x y.

  Definition eq_dec := eq_nat_dec.

End Nat_as_OT.
```

When I step through this on my own in Proof General, I get the error `Error: Proof editing in progress.` When I get to last line. It appears that it wants me to prove `lt_trans` before it accepts that the module is over. That's fair enough. But how is this working as part of the standard library if the proof is not there? Is it implicitly referencing some prior proof in a way I don't understand? Additional, if I do `Proof. Admitted.` to be able to skip past the Lemma proofs, it then wants a proof for `Definition compare x y : Compare lt eq x y.`. Why would it ask for a proof for a definition?

Comment: The html files do not show the proofs. See e.g. [here](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/2a857da2a88855a6c9f0fa7e48a8700c1613e0c7/theories/Structures/OrderedTypeEx.v#L50)

Comment: @AntonTrunov Brilliant. Thank You. Any Idea why its asking for a proof for a definition though? Is it to prove that the definition meets the specification required for being an `OrderedType`?

Comment: @AntonTrunov Is there any way to go straight from the html to the source, or do you have to go through the folders in the repo manually?

Comment: If you define something you must give the body of the definition. There are at least two ways of doing that: either you use an explicit term following `:=` (as you did with `eq_trans `) or you can use tactics to incrementally build the body. Since you put `.` instead of providing RHS, Coq enters the tactic mode and you have to build the body of `compare` with tactics.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to go straight to the source code. I almost always use my local copy of the standard library. And company-coq makes it easier to navigate it (there is this 'go to definition' function).

Comment: Not sure exactly what "building it up with tactics" means (I only know what it means to prove a Theorem or a Lemma with tactics), hopefully I'll figure it out over time as I get more familiar with Coq. Thank you so much for all of your help.

Comment: Here is a simple (I hope) [example](https://pastebin.com/mtuSjMKJ) demonstrating what I mean. It shows how to define the map function on lists using terms (usual functional programming) and tactics.